# Why doesn't TryParse accept an Object?

Tags: .net

I am curious about why the .NET TryParse methods (e.g. Int32.TryParse, DateTime.TryParse) do not accept an Object and instead accept a String for the first argument containing the number to be parsed. If I'm using TryParse, I'm keeping in mind that the method may fail and I'm using it for convenience. I would be fine with TryParse silently failing on the object and populating my result with 0 and returning false.

Comment: *What reason would a .NET Framework designer give me for making the first argument String* Because the code only deals with strings. You're basically asking why do we bother typing our parameters at all?

Comment: These methods are intended to translate string representing integers and dates, into integers and dates. Sure, they could provide sugar overrides that simply call `ToString` on their arguments, but that seems like not much help.

Comment: And for what it's worth, [`Convert.ToInt32(object)` exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx) (as do a lot of `ToSomeType(object)` functions) but they don't come in a `Try*` form.

Comment: @cbp Because then I could call `TryParse` with a `Guid` and have it return false, of course!

Comment: *I would like to call .ToString, but that could fail since I don't know the underlying type.* Well whoever implemented the underlying type is a bad programmer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx *Your ToString override should not throw an exception.*

Comment: *Ideally no code should throw an exception* Exceptions should be thrown in exceptional circumstances. Ergo, code should throw exceptions.

Comment: By that logic, why don't they make every method in the .NET framework accept an object?

Answer (score 5):

> What reason would a .NET Framework designer give me for making the first argument `String`?

Well you'd have to ask a .NET Framework designer instead of the community at Stack Overflow, but I'll take a crack.

1. The code only deals with `string`s.
2. Accepting an `object` and checking if it was a `string` would impose a performance penalty on everybody else using the function correctly.
3. Types like `Action<Guid>` can never meaningfully represent a number so using `string` instead of `object` makes calling the function with a meaningless type impossible (i.e. what result other than `false` could it possibly be? Save yourself the function call.)
4. You can emulate `TryParse` yourself with arbitrary `object`s using `try/catch` and [`Convert.ToInt32(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx).
5. It doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: +1
Item 5 should actually be on top of the list. 
It's *THE* argument: It simply doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: As far as curiosities go, [`Convert.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8.aspx) is a good one. Presumably included for symmetry.